# How to solve error '[True] not in index' and add the result in the document?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have no errors in this piece of code

```
df2 = df[["match","hteam_name", "ateam_name", "price_oh", "price_oa", "bookmaker_name"]].reset_index(drop=True)

df2
```

and this is the result

( I can't upload pictures because I still can't upload my reputation but the result is like a spreadsheet with the name of each column and the different data below. )

but if you want to calculate the average per game and bookmaker, only with non-zero odds I do this:

```
df2 = df[["match","hteam_name", "ateam_name", "price_oh" != 0.00, "price_oa", "bookmaker_name"]].reset_index(drop=True)

df2
```

and I get the error:

```
KeyError: '[True] not in index'
```

I don't understand why because I am only setting the odds to be different from zero because I want to average the odds per game and bookmaker and they have to be different from zero.

in addition I put this code for medium:

> `print(df2.groupby(["match"]).mean())`

but how to put this result in mi document like a column or a row?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your example `"price_oh" != 0.00` is evaluated to True because it only compares the string `price_oh` to `0`. If you want to filter on one of the series in your dataframe, you have to do it in a different way. For example, using `.loc` (doc: [pd.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)). Try this:

```py
df2 = df.loc[df["price_oh"] != 0.00, ["match","hteam_name", "ateam_name", "price_oh", "price_oa", "bookmaker_name"]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: yeah it work and I want the medium so I put

Comment: print(df2.groupby(["match"]).mean())

Comment: but how to append this result like a column or a row in my data frame?